# How to link interface target from upstream project using add_subdirectory in cmake?

Tags: cmake

```
- root
   - CmakeLists.txt
   - foo
      - foo.h
      - CmakeLists.txt
```

CmakeLists.txt at root:

```
set(TARGET_NAME main_target)
project(main_project)
add_subdirectory(foo)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME}
  INTERFACE
    foo::foo
)
```

CmakeLists.txt at foo:

```
set(PACKAGE_NAME foo)
set(INSTALL_CONFIGDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}/cmake)
add_library(foo INTERFACE)

# Install headers
install(FILES
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.h"
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# Install targets file
install(EXPORT install_targets
  FILE
    ${PACKAGE_NAME}Targets.cmake
  NAMESPACE
    ${PACKAGE_NAME}::
  DESTINATION
    ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)

# Install foo.cmake
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${PACKAGE_NAME}Config.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}Config.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)
install(FILES
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}Config.cmake
  DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)
```

I understand `foo` target makes an interface library. When I try to link my `main_target` to it though I get the error:

> Cannot specify link libraries for target "matplotlib_cpp" which is not built by this project

How can I solve this?

Comment: you talk about `foo` and then pull an error message about `matplotlib_cpp` out of nowhere. please make the error message correspond to your [mre].

Comment: Are you using an alias target that hasn't been defined for the `add_subdirectory` use-case? `foo/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't seem to have a `add_library(foo::foo ALIAS foo)`, which you seem to expect to exist (you use it in your `target_link_libraries`). What if you change your `target_link_libraries` to use `foo` instead of `foo::foo`, or add a line after the `add_subdirectory` defining the alias target `foo::foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define the target you want to link things to. If `TARGET_NAME` is the name of an executable, do `add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} <source files>)`, or if it's a library, use `add_library`. You have to do this *before* you try to do anything to configure the target (such as linking things with it), and usually have to do it before you refer to it in other configuration commands.

Your next problem will probably be that `foo::foo` isn't defined by your dependency for the `add_subdirectory` use-case- only for the import/export use-case. You'll probably need to add a manual `add_library(foo::foo ALIAS foo)` after doing `add_subdirectory(foo)`. I'd open a PR suggesting that that library do this for you. I'm assuming the library you're using is [`lava/matplotlib-cpp`](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising a PR like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for `cmake` [says](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#overview):

> target_link_libraries(`<target>` ... `<item>`... ...)

> The named `<target>` must have been created by a command such as add_executable() or add_library() and must not be an ALIAS target.

And the contents of `CMakeLists.txt` in your root directory are:

```
set(TARGET_NAME main_target)
project(main_project)
add_subdirectory(foo)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} # <-- see this line
  INTERFACE
    foo::foo
)
```

As you can see, you don't create a `target` with `add_library` or `add_executable`, so obviously you can't use `${TARGET_NAME}` directly.

Try:

```
set(TARGET_NAME main_target)
project(main_project)
add_subdirectory(foo)

# --------------------
add_library(${TARGET_NAME})
# --------------------

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} # <-- see this line
  INTERFACE
    foo::foo
)
```